# Is there any particular reason to declare float constants like this? (both C and C++)

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Is there any objective reason, besides readability or tradition, to declare float constants with a zero fractional part as `1.0f` as opposed to simply `1.f`?

This may simply be opinion based, but pretty much all the code I've seen online has it that way. Is it aiming to make adding a fractional part later easier (doubtful, since it involves one more erase) or simply for readability sake?

Should there be a difference between C and C++ regarding this, include both flavors.

Comment: No. Filler filler filler.

Comment: Hm. I see, alright. Let's wait for an answer or two, though if this proves to be a really pointless question, I'll close it.

Comment: Don't delete the question, it's good to have the answer available.

Comment: Ok, understood. I've been scared to an extent by the question standards lately, thus overreacting.

Comment: "Simply `1.f`"? To me, that is a strange abbreviation. But perhaps it is an American style thing, writing `1.` instead of `1.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, it is not necessary in C, nor C++ to have digits after the decimal point, not indeed before if some are present after.  It does not make a difference and is solely a matter of style to write `1.0f` or `1.f`.

Other languages differ on this syntactic choice to allow for the decimal point to be parsed as the member dereference operator.

- In Ruby for example, `1.f` would be parsed as `1` `.` `f` attempting to read property `f` of the number `1`.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's purely readability and tradition. It does not differ between C and C++.